# How do I conditionally render a form in Razor?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

When I use the following code, I get a friendly error message (as friendly as YSCD's get) telling me I shouldn't use '@', yet when I don't use it, my form declaration renders as literal Razor code, not as the intended HTML elements.  What am I doing wrong?

```
@if (Model.Step == Trocrates.Web.Models.PasswordResetModel.PasswordResetSteps.StartRequest)
{ 
        @using (Html.BeginForm()) { Html.ValidationSummary(true);
        <fieldset style="border: 0px;">
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName);
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName) Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)'
                <input type="submit" value="Log In" />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;@Html.ActionLink("Send", "BeginResetPassword", "Account")
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        }
}
```

*Sorry readers, it was originally that less visible open brace glyph on the same line as  BeginForm that caused confusion.  When I close that things fell back into place.*

Comment: Sorry, it's up there now, with my comment on what was wrong.  I think we leave this open in case other novices encounter it?

Comment: Isn't the main point of MVC separation of concerns? I see the view which has a logic and controls which part it will render. For me this should be handled by separate view for each "Model.Step" and the logic should be done by controller's action selecting correct view to render.

Comment: @Ladislav, I would agree 100% if I was considering having more logic in my view than simply what to display.  My view makes no business decisions i.e. what happens if an actor does 'this', simply 'what can the actor read having done that?'.  I have explored many-view based solutions to this problem while still using one basic view, but to avoid extra views differing in only one paragraph, sensible solutions seem to indicate my views recognising at least simple visibility flags set by the controllers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try removing the `@` symbol on the `using` statement? Since you're already in code mode because of the if block the `@` symbol doesn't mean anything there. That's the only thing off hand that looks out of place to me.